# lldb python error

Tags: macos, lldb

I tried running `lldb` on my mac and get this at startup:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Python/lldb/embedded_interpreter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import readline
ImportError: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so: no appropriate 64-bit architecture (see "man python" for running in 32-bit mode)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
```

I tried adding the environment variable `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes` but this error still appears. I'd reckon that the lldb is using a different python environment than it's Mac host so where do I make the change to make it use 32bit mode? thanks.

UPDATE:

I did an `arch -i386 lldb` and it works in 32-bit. To make it work in 64-bit, I installed a 64-bit version of python readline for OS X but got more problems with native python libraries such as `termios` and `time`. So I downloaded python 2.7.3 64-bit installer DMG file and installed its binary; now lldb works in 64 bit finally on my 10.8 mountain lion. Thanks.

Comment: I found this question after seeing this error on a `cordova run ios`. It didn't seem to affect the build making it to my physical device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you installed `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so` at some point on your system (I don't see it on my Mac OS X 10.7.5 installation, although maybe it's included in 10.8), and that dylib is only built 32-bit.  You can confirm with

```
file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
```

on your system.  You could try to force lldb to also run in 32-bit mode (the distribution binary is built 32-/64- universal) but instead I would recommend removing that 32-bit-only `readline.so` from your system unless you really need it there.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, running lldb in 32-bit works here. Readline is needed in LLDB to interpret python commands i guess, moving the .so file gave a import module not found error..

Comment: Interesting.  I poked around a little more and on my 10.7.5 system the Python framework is in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` and the `readline.so` in that framework is 2-way universal.  I still think you installed a package at some point in the past which is causing the problem ;) but if launching lldb as 32-bit works around it for you, it should be fine.

Comment: I manage to fix the problem by installing `six`; `pip install six`.

Comment: (re)install python2.7; /usr/local/bin/pip install six

Comment: @Oleander your comment deserves to be an answer. It worked for me

Comment: @Oleander, this worked for me. I don't know why it worked for me but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of anyone else coming to this question looking for a quick fix - Linus Oleander's answer worked for me -- that is, run

`pip install six`

Hazarding a guess as to *why* this works, I think this smooths over some python incompatibility issues that lldb is facing when running on machines with a 'non-standard' python installation. This also works when using Homebrew's version of llvm.